# Not giving Parent data from Child in association in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Hope you are doing good.

I am new in extjs4 and working on sample example of association.

I have 2 different class User and Diploma
In relation, I have defined.

**User hasMany Diplomas, and Diplomas belongsTo User**

**My models are as belows**

**User.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'userId',
    fields : [{
        name : 'userId',
        type : 'integer'
    }, {
        name : 'userName',
        type : 'string',

    }],

    hasMany : {
        model : 'MyApp.model.Diploma',
        name : 'diplomas',
    },

});
```

**Diploma.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Diploma', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'diplomaId',
    fields : [{
        name : 'diplomaId',
        type : 'integer'
    }, {
        name : 'diplomaName',
        type : 'string',
    }, {
        name : 'userId',
        type : 'integer'
    }],

    associations : [{
        model : 'MyApp.model.User',
        name : 'user',
        type : 'belongsTo'
    }]

});
```

=====================
My Stores are as below.========================

**Diploma.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Diploma', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'MyApp.model.Diploma',
    autoLoad : true,

    listeners : {
        'load' : {
            fn : function(store, records, success, operation) {
                console.log('Diplomas are loaded');
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**User.js**

```
  Ext.define('MyApp.store.User', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
        model : 'MyApp.model.User',
        requires:['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
        autoLoad : true,

        listeners : {
            'load' : {
                fn : function(store, records, success, operation) {
                    console.log('User is loaded');
                }
            }
        },

        data : [{
            userId : 1,
            userName : 'Rishabh Shah',
            diplomas:{
                userId : 1,
                diplomaId:1,
                diplomaName:'IT'
            }
        }, {
            userId : 2,
            userName : 'Rakesh Shah',
            diplomas:{
                userId : 2,
                diplomaId:2,
                diplomaName:'CE'
            }
        }, {
            userId : 3,
            userName : 'Rashmin Shah'
        }],

        proxy:{
            type:'memory',
            reader:{
                root:'data'
            }
        }
    });
```

I can get diploma from user like that and can get result

```
Ext.getStore("User").getAt(0).diplomasStore.getAt(0)
```

but, when I try to do like

```
Ext.getStrore("Diploma") or Ext.getStrore("Diploma").getAt(0)
```

I don't get anything. items contains nothing...
How can I get user from diploma.

and One more thing....if I don't write proxy in my Diploma model..
it gives me an error like this..

**Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.**

Please guide me.

Thanks.

---

Thanks for your reply..@john..I can get diplomas from User..
I wanted to get user from diplomas...I tried it myself..and found solution...

I will have following json.

```
[
    {
        "depId": 1,
        "depName": "CE",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Rishabh",
                "lastName": "Shah"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Smit",
                "lastName": "Patel"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 2,
        "depName": "IT",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag",
                "lastName": "Raval"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh",
                "lastName": "Prajapati"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 3,
        "depName": "EE",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag EE",
                "lastName": "Raval EE"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh EE",
                "lastName": "Prajapati EE"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 4,
        "depName": "EC",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag EC",
                "lastName": "Raval EC"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh EC",
                "lastName": "Prajapati EC"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 5,
        "depName": "Chemial E",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag",
                "lastName": "Raval"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh",
                "lastName": "Prajapati"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 6,
        "depName": "ME",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag",
                "lastName": "Raval"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh",
                "lastName": "Prajapati"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "depId": 7,
        "depName": "Civil Engineer",
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": 1,
                "firstName": "Parag",
                "lastName": "Raval"
            }, {
                "empId": 2,
                "firstName": "Rakesh",
                "lastName": "Prajapati"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and I will use **`model.getAssociatedData().user`**  as per my requirement

where **model is my record of child class and user is my parent class**..

and I was using proxy in my Diploma Model which was not requierd....so, was getting

**Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.**

above mentioned error.

Thanks All ! :)

Comment: Diploma belongs to a User, but when loading a diplomas you probably don't send the User with it.. So it has to load the User. And vice versa. The User-model is trying to load the Diploma's. It's not using the proxy on the diploma store but it uses the proxy on the diploma Model. When you don't define a proxy it creates one but this one doesn't have an api/url defined. The stores created by the associations are not Diploma stores or User stores but plain Ext.data.Store.

Comment: hey, @VDP thanks for the reply. 

I did not understand what you said in following sentense..

**It's not using the proxy on the diploma store but it uses the proxy on the diploma Model. When you don't define a proxy it creates one but this one doesn't have an api/url defined. The stores created by the associations are not Diploma stores or User stores but plain Ext.data.Store.**

will you please tell me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly isn't working? Have you been able to use the magic methods e.g., `User.diplomas()`? As @VDP stated, the store created for the Association is a normal `Ext.data.Store` scoped to the set of data for the parent model (in this case, User). That is to say, if you have a `User` model with the `id` of `1`, calling the method `User.diplomas()` will return a `Ext.data.Store` filtered to contain only `Diploma`'s with a `user_id` of `1`.

This is very important to understand! **If you do not specify the `foreignKey` property in a `hasMany` association, it will default to the lowercased name of the owner model plus "_id",** You should amend your `User` model's `hasMany` association as so:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.User', {
/** Model Definition */
hasMany : {
    model : 'MyApp.model.Diploma',
    name : 'diplomas',
    foreignKey : userId /** This is what you're missing */
}
});
```

Perhaps you will find this blog post useful? http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html

Some important tips from the blog post (in case the link dies at some point)

- Always put your Proxies in your Models, not your Stores, unless you
  have a very good reason not to *
- Always require your child models if using them in hasMany
  relationships. **
- Always use foreignKey if you want to load the children at will
- Always use associationKey if you return the children in the same
  response as the parent
- You can use both foreignKey and associationKey if you like
- Always name your hasMany relationships
- Always use fully qualified model names in your hasMany relationship
- Consider giving the reader root a meaningful name (other than "data")
- The child model does not need a belongsTo relationship for the
  hasMany to work

*The store will inherit its model's proxy, and you can always override it

**To make it easy, and avoid potential circular references, you can require them in app.js

Credit: Neil McGuigan (http://www.blogger.com/profile/14122981831780837323)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..@john..I can get diplomas from User..
I wanted to get user from diplomas...I tried it myself..and found solution...